# Render facebook open graph preview in page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

When using the javascript sdk the app opens a dialog with a link, facebook will fetch some sort of a display for that link, based on the og tags in it, and will put it inside an element with id "UIStoryAttachment".

Is there a way to somehow produce the same *UIStoryAttachment* display inside a container element of my choice? like, for example something similar to:

```
<div id="storyContainer">
    <div class="fb-story" data-url="MY_PAGE_URL"></div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("storyContainer"));
```

This of course does not exist, but is there anything similar in anyway?

Thanks.